# How can I edit WooCommerce menu?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want edit menu where can found "My Account", "My Orders", etc. I want include new links on that menu, but I can´t edit via admin panel and can´t found the template where woocommerce creates the menu.

Comment: Official related documentation: [Tabbed “My Account” pages in 2.6+](https://woocommerce.wordpress.com/2016/04/21/tabbed-my-account-pages-in-2-6/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can find a solution [here](http://wpbeaches.com/change-rename-woocommerce-endpoints-accounts-page/). 
it worked for me and i think it will be working for you too.

```
<?php
/*
* Add custom endpoint that appears in My Account Page - WooCommerce 2.6
* New URL below as Claudio changed his github username
* Ref - https://gist.github.com/claudiosanches/a79f4e3992ae96cb821d3b357834a005#file-custom-my-account-endpoint-php
*/


class My_Custom_My_Account_Endpoint
{

    /**
    * Custom endpoint name.
    *
    * @var string
    */
    public static $endpoint = 'my-custom-endpoint';

    /**
    * Plugin actions.
    */
    public function __construct()
    {
        // Actions used to insert a new endpoint in the WordPress.
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'add_endpoints' ) );
        add_filter( 'query_vars', array( $this, 'add_query_vars' ), 0 );

        // Change the My Accout page title.
        add_filter( 'the_title', array( $this, 'endpoint_title' ) );

        // Insering your new tab/page into the My Account page.
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', array( $this, 'new_menu_items' ) );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_account_' . self::$endpoint .  '_endpoint', array( $this, 'endpoint_content' ) );
    }

    /**
    * Register new endpoint to use inside My Account page.
    *
    * @see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_endpoint/
    */
    public function add_endpoints()
    {
        add_rewrite_endpoint( self::$endpoint, EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );
    }

    /**
    * Add new query var.
    *
    * @param array $vars
    * @return array
    */
    public function add_query_vars($vars)
    {
        $vars[] = self::$endpoint;

        return $vars;
    }

    /**
    * Set endpoint title.
    *
    * @param string $title
    * @return string
    */
    public function endpoint_title($title)
    {
        global $wp_query;

        $is_endpoint = isset( $wp_query->query_vars[ self::$endpoint ] );

        if ($is_endpoint && ! is_admin() && is_main_query() && in_the_loop() && is_account_page()) {
            // New page title.
            $title = __( 'My Stuff', 'woocommerce' );

            remove_filter( 'the_title', array( $this, 'endpoint_title' ) );
        }

        return $title;
    }

    /**
    * Insert the new endpoint into the My Account menu.
    *
    * @param array $items
    * @return array
    */
    public function new_menu_items($items)
    {
        // Remove the logout menu item.
        $logout = $items['customer-logout'];
        unset( $items['customer-logout'] );
        // Insert your custom endpoint.
        $items[ self::$endpoint ] = __( 'My Stuff', 'woocommerce' );

        // Insert back the logout item.
        $items['customer-logout'] = $logout;

        return $items;
    }

    /**
    * Endpoint HTML content.
    */
    public function endpoint_content()
    {
        wc_get_template( 'myaccount/navigation.php' ); ?>

        <div class="woocommerce-MyAccount-content">

            <p>Hello World! - custom field can go here</p>

        </div>

        <?php
    }

    /**
    * Plugin install action.
    * Flush rewrite rules to make our custom endpoint available.
    */
    public static function install()
    {
        flush_rewrite_rules();
    }
}

new My_Custom_My_Account_Endpoint();

// Flush rewrite rules on plugin activation.
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( 'My_Custom_My_Account_Endpoint', 'install' ) );
```